# Is it right to declare variables using macros in header file in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I encountered a problem when declare some global variables using macros. Here is the case:

**the original code:**

```
/* some_config.h */  
static const std::string KEYWORDS_A[] = {"AXX", "AYY"};  
static const std::vector<std::string>  KEYWORDS_A_VEC(KEYWORDS_A, KEYWORDS_A + sizeof(KEYWORDS_A) / sizeof(KEYWORDS_A[0]));  
static const std::string KEYWORDS_B[] = {"BXX", "BYY"};  
static const std::vector<std::string>  KEYWORDS_B_VEC(KEYWORDS_B, KEYWORDS_B + sizeof(KEYWORDS_B) / sizeof(KEYWORDS_B[0]));
```

**the current code:**

```
/* some_config.h */  
#define REGISTER_VEC(NAME) \  
static const std::vector<std::string>  KEYWORDS_##NAME_VEC(KEYWORDS_##NAME, KEYWORDS_##NAME + sizeof(KEYWORDS_##NAME) / sizeof(KEYWORDS_##NAME[0]))  
static const std::string KEYWORDS_A[] = {"AXX", "AYY"};  
REGISTER_VEC(A);  
static const std::string KEYWORDS_B[] = {"BXX", "BYY"};  
REGISTER_VEC(B);
```

the some_config.h was included in some.cpp in which the variables KEYWORDS_A_VEC and  KEYWORDS_B_VEC were used. However, for **the current code**, the g++ compiler will give an error of not finding the definition of KEYWORDS_A_VEC and KEYWORDS_A_VEC.
Is there anything wrong with the code? thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this has to do with how the preprocessor recursively fills in macros that appear in macro expansions.  I know comparatively little on this subject, so I'll leave it to another C++ expert to help out on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compilation problem is caused because you need a tokenization thing in every place that you intend to tokenize, e.g.:

```
#define REGISTER_NAME(NAME) blah_##NAME##_blah
```

(Note use of `##` on *both* sides of `NAME`.)

As to whether this is good practice, I would say no.  You have a single macro instantiating multiple variables, which is confusing to the reader of your code.  Many IDEs and debuggers will get confused by this sort of thing, which means that a reader will have to do a lot of manual hunting to work out where variables are magically being declared.

Comment: And don't forget, when you get confusing error messages from macros, g++ -E is your friend - it fires it through the preprocessor, allowing you to see what the compiler sees at that point